# How to remove the .html at the end of a website hyperlink?

Tags: html

This may be a super easy fix but every time I look online for answers I only find how to remove underlining on links in HTML.

I am looking to remove the **.html** from the end of the hyperlinks for my website, currently, it is **www.mydomain/index.html**, how could I remove the .html and even possibly make it show something like **www.mydomain/home** .

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What server/hosting/framework do you use?

Comment: Currently just hosting it off GitHub pages at the moment @RosdiKasim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is create a file named ".htaccess" in the root directory of your site with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Then you have to make sure that none of your files contain ".html" at the end. So if you have something like:

```
<a href="/about.html">
```

Go ahead and replace it with:

```
<a href="/about">
```